# How do you get the path of the running script in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I'm writing a groovy script that I want to be controlled via a properties file stored in the same folder.  However, I want to be able to call this script from anywhere.  When I run the script it always looks for the properties file based on where it is run from, not where the script is.

How can I access the path of the script file from within the script?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of Groovy 2.3.0 the [`@SourceURI`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/SourceURI.html) annotation can be used to populate a variable with the URI of the script's location.  This URI can then be used to get the path to the script:

```groovy
import groovy.transform.SourceURI
import java.nio.file.Path
import java.nio.file.Paths

@SourceURI
URI sourceUri

Path scriptLocation = Paths.get(sourceUri)
```

Note that this will only work if the URI is a `file:` URI (or another URI scheme type with an installed [FileSystemProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html)), otherwise a [FileSystemNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileSystemNotFoundException.html) will be thrown by the `Paths.get(URI)` call.  In particular, certain Groovy runtimes such as groovyshell and nextflow return a `data:` URI, which will not typically match an installed `FileSystemProvider`.

Comment: `java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "data" not installed`

Comment: @HuguesFontenelle What's the `sourceUri` value when you get that exception?  Or does that happen on the `@SourceUri` line and not when you convert it to a `Path`?

Comment: `sourceUri` is a map containing ```[rawAuthority:null, opaque:true, scheme:data, rawQuery:null, port:-1, rawUserInfo:null, path:null, class:class java.net.URI, absolute:true, schemeSpecificPart:,CONTENT, rawPath:null, query:null, fragment:null, host:null, authority:null, rawFragment:null, userInfo:null, rawSchemeSpecificPart:,CONTENT]``` (where CONTENT is my serialized script).
The `path` and `rawPath` keys have `null` value.

Comment: @HuguesFontenelle According to the docs for @SourceURI, the resulting value will be an instance of `java.net.URI`; plus the map you're showing are the properties of the `java.net.URI` class.  Are you sure it's actually a map that's being set, and not actually a `URI`?  Regardless, this looks like a data URL, not a file URL.  Is the source of the script actually a local file, and not something that's been serialized over the network or something like that?  In that case, there wouldn't even be a corresponding file, which explains why you couldn't convert it to a `Path`.

Comment: @HuguesFontenelle How are you running the script?  Per the answers to this question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240588/how-to-use-sourceuri-annotation-to-retrieve-the-full-path-of-the-script-file-in ), the `@SourceURI` approach does not work if running from the Groovy console, which I've confirmed locally.  What happens when you run the script directly from the command line?  e.g. `groovy sourceUriTest.groovy`, replacing "`sourceUriTest.groovy`" with your actual script file?

Comment: I'm using [nextflow](https://www.nextflow.io) which uses groovy, and I just found out that the file path was available to me using `workflow.scriptFile` (or `workflow. projectDir` for the dir path). Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: @HuguesFontenelle I've updated the question for the scenario with no matching `FileSystemProvider`.

Answer (score 89):

You are correct that `new File(".").getCanonicalPath()` does not work.  That returns the *working directory*.

To get the script directory

```
scriptDir = new File(getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path).parent
```

To get the script file path

```
scriptFile = getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path
```

Comment: Interesting.  It doesn't work the way I expected it to.  But that is due to the fact I am running a gant script from gant.  So the codeSource is actually where gant is, not where my script is.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  `getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource` returns null.  I'm using Groovy 2.0.1.

Comment: Doesn't work on 1.11 either, returns something like: .gradle/caches/1.11/scripts/build_189dc3r2nd588m3657jv5d36h7..

Comment: It works for me in groovy 1.8.5 on OSx with a Java 8 install.

Comment: Confirmed that it works in Windows with Groovy version 2.1.5.

Comment: I am using maven and it gives me the path of target directory... :)

Comment: @quux00: Try `MyClassName.class.protectionDomain.codeSource` instead (ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747833/getting-filesystem-path-of-class-being-executed )

Comment: depending on how it's run, I get either `/groovy` for the parent or the correct directory. What about this: `getClass().getResource('/${yourScript}.groovy')` That works for me assuming your script is on the classpath

Answer (score 11):

This makes sense if you are running the Groovy code *as a script*, otherwise the whole idea gets a little confusing, IMO.  The workaround is here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1642

Basically this involves changing startGroovy.sh to pass in the location of the Groovy script as an environment variable.

> As long as this information is not provided directly by Groovy, it's possible to modify the groovy.(sh|bat) starter script to make this property available as system property:
> For unix boxes just change $GROOVY_HOME/bin/groovy (the sh script) to do
>
> ```shell
> export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dscript.name=$0"
> ```
>
> before calling startGroovy
> For Windows:
> In startGroovy.bat add the following 2 lines right after the line with
> the :init label (just before the parameter slurping starts):
>
> ```
> @rem get name of script to launch with full path
> set GROOVY_SCRIPT_NAME=%~f1
> ```
>
> A bit further down in the batch file after the line that says "set
> JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dgroovy.starter.conf="%STARTER_CONF%" add the
> line
>
> ```
> set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dscript.name="%GROOVY_SCRIPT_NAME%"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

**For gradle user**

I have same issue when I'm starting to work with gradle. I want to compile my thrift by remote thrift compiler (custom by my company).

Below is how I solved my issue:

```
task compileThrift {
doLast {
        def projectLocation = projectDir.getAbsolutePath(); // HERE is what you've been looking for.
        ssh.run {
            session(remotes.compilerServer) {
                // Delete existing thrift file.
                cleanGeneratedFiles()
                new File("$projectLocation/thrift/").eachFile() { f ->
                    def fileName=f.getName()
                    if(f.absolutePath.endsWith(".thrift")){
                        put from: f, into: "$compilerLocation/$fileName"
                    }
                }
                execute "mkdir -p $compilerLocation/gen-java"
                def compileResult = execute "bash $compilerLocation/genjar $serviceName", logging: 'stdout', pty: true
                assert compileResult.contains('SUCCESSFUL')
                get from: "$compilerLocation/$serviceName" + '.jar', into: "$projectLocation/libs/"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One more solution. It works perfect even you run the script using GrovyConsole

```
File getScriptFile(){
    new File(this.class.classLoader.getResourceLoader().loadGroovySource(this.class.name).toURI())
}

println getScriptFile()
```

Answer (score 0):

**workaround**: for us it was running in an ANT environment and storing some location parent (knowing the subpath) in the Java environment properties (`System.setProperty( "dirAncestor", "/foo" )`) we could access the dir ancestor via Groovy's `properties.get('dirAncestor')`.
maybe this will help for some scenarios mentioned here.