# How to find current base execution directory in groovy (or java)?

Tags: java, groovy

I've got a little script I'm using a paramter to pass in the current execution directory, but would like to make it a little more robust.

How does one find out the base execution directory?

Comment: Related Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163093/how-do-you-get-the-path-the-running-script-in-groovy

Comment: Thanks Tim. I have used the accepted answer on that question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For reference:

The accepted answer on the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163093/how-do-you-get-the-path-the-running-script-in-groovy) is what I was looking for.

As an example, when calling `c:\scripts\MyScript.groovy` from `c:\users\Scott\` I wanted to know `c:\scripts\`.

This is done via this:

`def scriptDir = getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path`

Where scriptDir is assigned something like:

`/c:/scripts/MyScript.groovy`

Comment: Yes, your question isn't worded well.  You needed to ask "how to get the location of the class". Glad you found the answer though.

Answer (score 50):

Try this:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Comment: Yes this was the first idea, but it only gives the path from where the script is called from, not where the script lives (my question is probably worded a little confusingly).

Comment: or `System.properties['user.dir']` a bit shorter with groovy syntax.

Comment: @Ibrahim.H or `System.properties.'user.dir'` for even slightly shorter Groovy syntax! :D

Answer (score 29):

Depending on the security model, if the `System.getProperty(String)` is not allowed, you can use

```
String currentDir = new File(".").getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: That workaround won't help.  The javadoc for `getAbsolutePath()` says throws *"`SecurityException` - If a required system property value cannot be accessed."*

Comment: It should be new File(".").getAbsoluteFile().getParent() - this removes the trailing "/." from the path.