# Grails Plugin Get Plugin's Root or Installed Directory

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm writing a plugin and I'm trying to write a file inside of the Plugin's root or installed directory (not sure what to refer to this to).  I can't seem to figure out how to get a hold of this value.  Doing `System.properties['base.dir']` will result in the implementing Grails project's root directory.  So right now I have two directories:

C:/PluginProject/

C:/GrailsAppThatUsesPlugin/

It's my understanding that when this becomes a distributed plugin a user will similarly have two directories:

GRAILS_HOME/grails-version/projects/projectName/plugins/myPlugin/

C:/GrailsAppThatUsesPlugin/

Inside of my plugin project I need to create a file.  It needs to be inside of my plugin because the file I'm writing needs to reference other files that my plugin provides.  The few things that I've tried that haven't worked are:

1. `System.properties['base.dir']`
2. `new File("")`
3. In a groovy script within a plugin you can simply refer to `pluginNamePluginDir` but I'm trying to access this from a POGO.
4. Looking at all of the `System.properties` none of them have the plugin directory
5. grailsApplication doesn't seem to contain this type of information either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder

def pluginManager = PluginManagerHolder.pluginManager
def plugin = pluginManager.getGrailsPlugin(pluginName)
def pluginDir = plugin.descriptor.file.parentFile
```

The plugin name has to be of the form `'spring-security-core'`, not `'springSecurityCore'`

Comment: I put this code in a test and `plugin.descriptor` is always null.  The `plugin` is not null.  Also if I do `plugin.getPluginDir()` that throws a NPE.  Any thoughts?  Do I need to configure something for the descriptor to be available?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I ended up using something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163093/how-do-you-get-the-path-the-running-script-in-groovy.  It got me the path that I was looking for.  I was able to use the PluginManagerHolder to get other information I needed.  Thanks Burt!

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me (both in-place and regular plug-ins):

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginUtils

GrailsPluginUtils.pluginInfos.find { it.name == pluginName }.pluginDir
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using this way to avoid the find operation:
`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginUtils.getPluginDirForName(pluginName).file.absolutePath`