# How to know if a grails plugin is running standalone or when the plugin is installed into the application

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Basically I want to retrieve the same value provided by the ["pluginContextPath"](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#12.3%20Understanding%20a%20Plug-ins%20Structure) variable used in a gsp but in a groovy class.

---

class {

String pluginCtx = $pluginContextPath

byte[] logo = grailsApplication.getParentContext().servletContext.getResource("${pluginCtx}images/myImage.jpg").bytes;

}

---

I know that I cannot use the $pluginContextPath variable in a groovy class, but I tried using something suggested in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235840/grails-plugin-get-plugins-root-or-installed-directory) but it gives me the dir full path

GrailsPluginUtils.pluginInfos.find { it.name == pluginName }.pluginDir

but what i want is what the [pluginContextPath](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#12.3%20Understanding%20a%20Plug-ins%20Structure)  variable does

"When you run the plugin in development mode the link to the resource will resolve to something like /js/mycode.js. However, when the plugin is installed into an application the path will automatically change to something like /plugin/example-0.1/js/mycode.js and Grails will deal with making sure the resources are in the right place."

Comment: I found a way to get it using the PluginManagerHolder. String grailsPluginContext = PluginManagerHolder.pluginManager.getPluginPath('my-plugin')