# Getting filesystem path of class being executed

Tags: java, filepath

Is there any way to determine current filesystem location of executed class from the code of this class, in runtime, given that it's executed using `java` command?

For example for following class:

```
public class MyClass{
 public static void main(String[] args){\
   new MyClass().doStuff();
 }

 private void doStufF(){
   String path = ... // what to do here?!
   System.out.println("Path of class being invoked: " + path);
 }

}
```

Is there any way to get and print the correct path in filesystem of MyClass.class file just being invoked?

Similarly, if I invoke jar file from `java -jar` command, is there any way to get a path of jar file from within classes inside that jar?

P.S.:Please, **do not make any assumptions about working directory** from which `java` command is invoked!

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The following code snippet will do this for you:

```
final File f = new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```

<sub>replace `MyClass` with your `main` class</sub>

The resulting `File` object `f` represents the `.jar` file that was executed. You can use this object to get the parent to find the directory that the `.jar` is in.

Comment: Beware when doing this: if your class file is somewhere in a directory that has a space in it, the returned string (which is the path part of a URL, which getLocation() returns, and is therefore URL encoded) will contain '%20' instead of spaces!

Comment: @JandeVos Using the `File(java.net.URI)` constructor seems to fix that issue.

Comment: @Spooky's comment: so it must be `final File f = new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getURI().getPath());`

Comment: I am trying this, but it is returning the path of the folder where I ran the command instead of the subfolder with the class file.