# Create .txt file inside project

Tags: java

I want to create a new `.txt` file inside my project folder and I want to give it this path:

```
Contents/FrameClasses/Data/Datafiles/MYFILE.txt
```

What I use to make the folder is this:

```
File MYFILE = new File("Contents/FrameClasses/Data/Datafiles/MYFILE.txt");
MYFILE.getParentFile().mkdir();
try{
    if(MYFILE.createNewFile()){
        //do stuff here
    }
}catch (Exception e){
    //do stuff with the exception...
}
```

Whenever I do this I get an error saying:

> java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

The error is fixed if I add `src/` to the beginning of my path and make it like this:

```
src/Contents/FrameClasses/Data/Datafiles/MYFILE.txt
```

But the `src/` is not part of my project as **everything** is contained inside the `Contents` folder I've made. When I build the `.jar` file it gives the same error if I run it once I add the `src/` to the path.

What would be the proper way to create this file ?
**PS**: I've tried using a shorter path like this one as well: `Datafiles/MYFILE.txt` without success. Also, the class I use to make the file is contained inside the folder `Data` alongside with `Datafiles` as shown in the original path.

Comment: try fully pathing it from '/' You are currently using a relative path from where you are running the code from. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747833/getting-filesystem-path-of-class-being-executed

Comment: @ScaryWombat That way it would work but what I am trying to achieve is to create the text file **inside** the project even once it becomes a `.jar` file.

Comment: so the `.jar` file could be anywhere, that is why you need to use a full path

Comment: You can't create a file within a jar file at runtime. It'd be outside of it

Comment: Why? The project won't be there at runtime. You should be looking to create the file relative to the JAR location, or the user's home directory, or a temp directory, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer: You should not write file into in class folder.**

In the **runtime**, we will run **Java Program** with **jar file**, and **jar** essentially is a **zip** file, you can not write into your own runtime **jar** like this directly by path. if you run this with a **jar** file, it maybe will throw exception like:

```
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

And:

1. `src/Contents/FrameClasses/Data/Datafiles/MYFILE.txt` this path work, I think you are running in your IDE or other way, but not run with a released **jar file**.
2. `File MYFILE = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/").getPath() + "Contents/FrameClasses/Data/Datafiles/MYFILE.txt")` should work when you run without a **jar**.