# Reload static content spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, static, gulp, browser-sync

I am using Netbeans and I am developing my first web application using spring boot. I was keeping my HTML, js, CSS in "webapp" folder and then I refactored my project and I put all static content in `/resources/static`. Since then, I have to rebuild my project every time because the static content isn't reloaded.

Can I easily bypass this problem if I'll use browser-sync plugin for Gulp?

Answer (score 50):

Add the following to src/main/resources/application.properties:

```
spring.web.resources.static-locations[0]=file:src/main/resources/static/
spring.web.resources.static-locations[1]=classpath:/static/
```

The "file:" causes the content to be reloaded on refreshing the browser,
[see related issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5133#issuecomment-374630188).

Alternatively, the file [resource locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747833/getting-filesystem-path-of-class-being-executed) can be [discovered](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-autowire) at runtime and [added programmatically](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceHandlerRegistration.html#addResourceLocations-java.lang.String...-).

See also [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-webflux-static-content) and [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources).

Note that prior to Spring Boot 2.4, the property was called "spring.resources.static-locations".

Comment: I also had to remove my registry.addResourceHandler().addResourceLocations() from method addResourceHandlers in WebMvcConfigurer interface, otherwise i only could get the content if the directory was already created by the application. Now it´s working, thanks for this black magik

Comment: Just an update - it's now `spring.web.resources.static-locations` instead of `spring.resources.static-locations`

Comment: Similarly, for loading Thymeleaf templates directly from the source directory in development, instead of the default `classpath:/templates/`, set `spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:src/main/resources/templates/`

Answer (score 2):

if an application.yml file is used for configuration, insert:

```
spring:
  web:
    resources:
      static-locations[0]: "file:src/main/resources/static/"
      static-locations[1]: "classpath:/static/"
```

Comment: note that in yaml the [n] suffix is not necessary, you can specify 'static-locations' as a map key and then the two strings can be list items (indicated by "- ")

Comment: Hi, do these indexes [0] and [1] indicate the hierarchy of files? If the file is found in the [0] location, it is loaded; otherwise, the [1] location is checked, and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Normally the static content is copied to the build directory ( target if you are using maven) by the spring-boot plugin. You can find your files at {build-directory}/classes/static: These are the files that you should modify to reflect changes. You should also copy your changes to resources/static, because whenever you restart spring boot, the files are copied.

Comment: ok but i would like to modify resources/static and the changes to reflect.

Comment: Then you should check out spring-boot-dev-tools https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html