# Spring Boot Download File Into Static File But 404 Error

Tags: spring, spring-boot

After clicking a button I download the file into src/main/resources/static/download/play/1.mp3.Everything is OK until here.

But I can't access the file and also got 404 error even though file downloaded.

How can i reach the audio?

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide any information on how your application is written, built or deployed, or what URL you're expecting your audio file to be available under so it's impossible to tell with any degree of certainty what may be wrong.

I'm going to take a stab in the dark and say that the answer is somewhere in [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources).

Edit:

It seems that I was right. According to the article I linked to above, if you place your file in `src/main/resources/static/download/play/1.mp3`, it’ll be available under `http://localhost:8080/static/download/play/1.mp3` and not under `http://localhost:8080/download/play/1.mp3`. You need to either move the file or change the link.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am using spring boot, thymeleaf. If I click the download button on index page send the get request to /download-file and download the file i want into src/main/resources/static/download/play/downloadedfilename.mp3 . I got HTML <audio> src Attribute and I want the downloaded file to be heard.But i cant reach the file. http://localhost:8080/download/play/downloadedfilename.mp3 is return 404 error. Thank you.

Comment: I found the solution I added to application.properties                     spring.resources.static-locations[0]=file:src/main/resources/static/
spring.resources.static-locations[1]=classpath:/static/            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43693393/reload-static-content-spring-boot-application

Comment: That was also mentioned in the article I linked. I did not mention it in my answer as I feel that moving the file or changing the link is easier than changing configuration. Although I’m wondering why are you adding the same directory twice to the static locations list.