# Spring Boot - IntellIj: hot swapping does not work for resources/static folder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, hotswap

I started working on spring boot project recently. I have project structure as shown below image.

**Problem**: When I change any js/css files under resource/static folder, IDE fails to do hot swap. I am using **spring-boot-devtools**, Thymeleaf resources are updated properly after changing template without restarting application.

**Spring Boot Version**: 2.0.3

**IDE Environment**:

```
IDEA 2018.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-181.4892.42, built on May 8, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b38 x86
JVM: OpenJDK Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 7 6.1
```

**Thymeleaf Configuration in application.properties**

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.templates_root=src/main/resources/templates/
```

[image: My Project Structure]

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47677886/4763309

Comment: @mrkernelpanic, it works. But i need that with out clicking build project. Actually Previously i used netbeans it works with out rebuild option.