# Listing files from resource directory in sbt 1.2.8

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a Scala application which processes binary files from some directory in `resources`. I would like to get this directory as `java.io.File` and list all the contents. In the newest sbt I am unable to do it the straight way.

I have created minimal repo with my issue:

https://github.com/mat646/sbt-resource-bug

The issue does not occur with `sbt` 0.13.18 and lower.
So after some research I've found out that since `sbt` 1.0 the design has changed and such issue has been already addressed here:

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3963

So the offered solutions were:

1. downgrade to `sbt` 0.13 (which I would like to avoid)
2. extracting project jar itself (which I found pretty nagging, as I still haven't solved it yet - the https://github.com/sbt/io contains `gunzip` method but for me it still fails to extract my directory from jar, but here I might be misunderstanding how to extract nested file from project jar)
   (so as the `sbt` 1.0+ works on build jar for reading files `getResourceAsStream` works perfectly but fails for my issue)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`run` task seems to have been rewired in [Forward run task to bgRun #3477](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/3477/files#diff-6373e7f7122325e753b75fe1cc76ff5fL507) and one side-effect was to use packaged jars on classpaths instead of class directories, so that `getClass.getResource("/my-dir")` returns

```
jar:file:/var/folders/84/hm7trc012j19rbgtn2h4fg6c0000gp/T/sbt_1397efb8/job-1/target/43a04671/sbt-resource-bug_2.12-0.1.jar!/my-dir
```

instead of

```
file:/Users/amani/IdeaProjects/sbt-resource-bug/target/scala-2.12/classes/my-dir
```

### Workaround 1 : Redefine `run` to the old behaviour

As a workaround, we could try reverting the rewiring in our `build.sbt` like so:

```
run := Defaults.runTask(fullClasspath in Runtime, mainClass in run in Compile, runner in run).evaluated
```

Now `File.listFiles` should work, for example,

```
new File(getClass.getResource("/my-dir").getFile).listFiles().foreach(println)
```

should output

```
sbt:sbt-resource-bug> run
[info] Running Main 
/Users/mario/IdeaProjects/sbt-resource-bug/target/scala-2.12/classes/my-dir/file2.txt
/Users/mario/IdeaProjects/sbt-resource-bug/target/scala-2.12/classes/my-dir/file1.txt
```

### Workaround 2: Use `JarFile` to work with JARs directly

Alternatively, if we wish to keep the current rewiring, [`JarFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) can be used to list the contents of JAR files. For example, given

```
object ListFileNamesInJarDirectory {
  def apply(dir: String): List[String] = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters.enumerationAsScalaIteratorConverter
    val jar = new File(getClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath())
    (new JarFile(jar))
      .entries()
      .asScala
      .toList
      .filter(!_.isDirectory)
      .filter(entry => entry.getRealName.contains(dir))
      .map(_.getName)
  }
}
```

then

```
ListFileNamesInJarDirectory("my-dir").foreach(println)
```

should output

```
my-dir/file1.txt
my-dir/file2.txt
```

Afterwards, `getResourceAsStream` can be used to get at the actual files in the jar. Note [how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11747859/5205022) we get `File` to represent the jar file:

```
val jar = new File(getClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such comprehensive answer! This precisely solves my issue! 
Both workarounds work seamlessly, but could you give additional opinion on these solutions?   

Second method is clear to me and it definitely avoids unpacking whole project jar to some tmp/ directory as some users on github issue suggested. 

In first one I'm unfamiliar with sbt internals.
So are there any costs (performance, safety) which I might bear due to such rewiring? Or can I losslessly use it?