# Sending data before execution of scenarios

Tags: scala, cucumber

I am working on a scala application. I have some files in my resouce folder of project. Those are json files. I want to load all of them as string and send them over to kafka topic. I already have kafka producer code but just don't know how to all files and send them. I am using following code

```
Source.fromResource(path_of_file).mkstring
```

But  with this I am able to send only one file which I  pass but how can I write a generic code to load them and send them one by one. This thing I need to do in BeforeAll of my cucumber test. In short I just want to send these files before my any scenario begin to  execute

Comment: Did you have a look at the `java.nio.files` package and this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html? That could contian what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Which sbt version are you using? Please note that [sbt 1.2.8 has a bug in listing directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55493096/listing-files-from-resource-directory-in-sbt-1-2-8). Otherwise the following should do that:

```
new File(getClass.getResource("/my-dir").getFile).listFiles().foreach(println)
```

Comment: Just one more query. In intellij I am not getting the option of BeforeAll . Only Before and BeforeStep option available. I want to load these files at the starting of all of the test case not at every step. Do you know how I can do it?

Comment: Make sure you are importing org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll, and extending BeforeAndAfterAll. It comes from the scalatest package, so make sure you import it at your build.sbt file.

Comment: I added  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest"   % "3.1.2" % Test, in my build.sbt. But still no  BeforeAll option I am getting