# How to detect file location in Java Classes?

Tags: java

Lets take a class A.

```
class A{
 
  public getAbsoluteLocation(){
    
   ....
  }
}
```

How can this class know in which directory it is located?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting filesystem path of class being executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747833/getting-filesystem-path-of-class-being-executed)

Comment: Yes but most likely getAbsoluteLocation() should be a string and should return its corresponding datatype.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227486/find-where-java-class-is-loaded-from

Comment: It isn't necessarily located in a filesystem directory at all. More likely a JAR or WAR or EAR file.

Comment: @VladislavVarslavans No it doesn't. That gives you the location of the JAR file, not of the current class.

Comment: class can have no file, it can be downloaded over network or even generated dynamically.

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption is that you just want to print the path. You can also return the value or perform any other operations based on your method return type.

```
class A {
 
  public void getAbsoluteLocation() {
    ClassLoader loader = A.class.getClassLoader();
    System.out.println(A.class.getResource("A.class"));
  }

}
```