# get path to groovy source file at runtime

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

Given the following directory structure:

```
/home/some/random/foler/myScript.grooy
```

... how can I programmatically obtain the path to myScript.grooy parent directory right in the script itself?

Ultimately I'm trying to read in several files from the same directory the script is in.

**EDIT:** trying to run it on Windows 7, Groovy 2.0.1, groovy console

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the path of the running script in groovy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163093/how-do-you-get-the-path-of-the-running-script-in-groovy)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get the path of the running script in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163093/how-do-you-get-the-path-of-the-running-script-in-groovy)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, the solution is in Java's File class:

```
println new File(".").absolutePath
```

If you want to obtain every groovy script in the same directory, maybe you could use some of other facilities in the Groovy JDK, like `eachFile`:

```
def files = []
new File(".").eachFile { 
    if (it.name.endsWith(".groovy") ) files << it 
}
println files
```

If you want the running script name, well, you've got a problem (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1642)

Accordingly to that JIRA, this is the current workaround (which doesn't always work):

```
URL scriptUrl = getClass().classLoader.resourceLoader
    .loadGroovySource(getClass().name)
```

Comment: ... hm, File(".").absolutePath gives me "C:\Users\userNameHere\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Groovy\." and workaround does not work either, bummer :-(

Comment: Aren't you running groovy through cmd?

Comment: goovy console, would that make a difference?

Comment: I run it through my shell, and not groovyconsole, maybe that is the problem: it ends up getting the path to groovyconsole instead of the script