# How to use @SourceURI annotation to retrieve the full path of the script file in Groovy 2.3?

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I need to retrieve at runtime the full path of the script file in Groovy 2.3.
Actually I have the same problem than the one described here: [get path to groovy source file at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958185/get-path-to-groovy-source-file-at-runtime).

My script can be executed from GroovyShell or not.

My script is located at :

```
C:\users\myname\documents\scripts\myscript.groovy
```

**=> I simpy want to retrieve this path at runtime.**

If I use the solution that was accepted:

```
println new File(".").absolutePath
```

what I get is actually :

```
C:\groovy-2.3.7\.
```

which is the groovy home folder. That is not correct.
The other proposed answer ie :

```
URL scriptUrl = getClass().classLoader.resourceLoader.loadGroovySource(getClass().name)
```

works only when my script is in the classpath, or when it is loaded at groovy startup using load directive in groovy-starter.conf. Otherwise it returns null. I could use this method but it is not satisfying because it is like passing a parameter and the goal here is that users to be able to execute the script from anywhere without modification or configuration.

I also red this JIRA who focus on this question: 
[JIRA-1642](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-1642)

Solution seems to use the **@SourceURI annotation** that was created for this purpose. Problem is I am not able to make it work. I try to execute the code usage shown at: [SourceURI](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/SourceURI.html)

```
@groovy.transform.SourceURI def sourceURI
assert sourceURI instanceof java.net.URI
path = sourceURI.toString()
println "path = $path"
```

What I get is (groovy 2.3.7) is not the path but the source code :

```
path = data:,@groovy.transform.SourceURI%20def%20sourceURI%0A%0A%20assert%20sourceURI%20instanceof%20java.net.URI%0Apath%20=%20sourceURI.toString()%0Aprintln%20%22path%20=%20$path%22
```

How to use the @SourceURI annotation to retrieve the path of the script file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking for the same script path information you were.  I noticed that when running the following via the shell:

```
@groovy.transform.SourceURI def sourceURI
assert sourceURI instanceof java.net.URI
sourceURI.properties.each { i -> 
    println i
}
```

I get the following, useful results (note the value in path):

```
rawAuthority=null
opaque=false
scheme=file
rawQuery=null
port=-1
rawUserInfo=null
path=/home/ttresans/GroovyScripts/TestSourceURI.groovy
class=class java.net.URI
absolute=true
schemeSpecificPart=/home/ttresans/GroovyScripts/TestSourceURI.groovy
rawPath=/home/ttresans/GroovyScripts/TestSourceURI.groovy
query=null
fragment=null
host=null
authority=null
rawFragment=null
userInfo=null
rawSchemeSpecificPart=/home/ttresans/GroovyScripts/TestSourceURI.groovy
```

But if I paste the same thing into the GroovyConsole, I get the following:

```
rawAuthority=null
opaque=true
scheme=data
rawQuery=null
port=-1
rawUserInfo=null
path=null
class=class java.net.URI
absolute=true
schemeSpecificPart=,@groovy.transform.SourceURI def sourceURI
assert sourceURI instanceof java.net.URI
sourceURI.properties.each { i -> 
    println i
}

rawPath=null
query=null
fragment=null
host=null
authority=null
rawFragment=null
userInfo=null
rawSchemeSpecificPart=,@groovy.transform.SourceURI%20def%20sourceURI%0Aassert%20sourceURI%20instanceof%20java.net.URI%0AsourceURI.properties.each%20%7B%20i%20-%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20println%20i%0A%7D%0A
```

This is on Groovy 2.3.9 on Ubuntu.

So it seems like the GroovyConsole's startup might be a problem, but the annotation does in fact produce the desired path.

Comment: Thanks for the tests of the annotation, you are perfectly right. It is the path I needed to retrieve, even there is apparently no possibility to use the annotation from the GroovyConsole.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going through the protection domain, like this:

[How do you get the path of the running script in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163093/how-do-you-get-the-path-of-the-running-script-in-groovy)

Comment: I did but it doesn't work (what I get is :/groovy/shell)