jenkins shared library large amount of shell scripts
I have a shared jenkins library, that contains a large number of shell scripts. These shell scripts source each other.
I know I can copy individual files using libraryResource. Since I'd be copying a lot of files I'd prefer to call the scripts where they are.
My directory structure
+
|- resource
   |-script1.sh
   |-script2.sh
|- var
   |-bar.groovy (calls script1.sh, which needs script2.sh)

bar.groovy looks like this
def call(){
    script {
        withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'my-ssh', keyFileVariable: 'ssh_key', passphraseVariable: 'ssh_pass', usernameVariable: 'ssh_user')]) {
            scriptDir = new File(getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path).parent
            sh "sh ${scriptDir}/../resources/script1.sh -u $ssh_user -i $ssh_key -b ${env.BUILD_ID}"
        }
    }
}

My Jenkinsfile looks something like this
@Library('mylib')
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage("calling script") {
           steps {
              bar()
           }
        }
    }
}

I tried variations, but I cannot get the location of bar.groovy
new File(getClass().protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path) 
//  /opt/jenkins/plugins/workflow-cps/WEB-INF/lib/workflow-cps.jar
new File(".") 
// /opt/jenkins/.
__FILE__
// not defined (found in the Job-DSL documentation)

I know getClass returns the Java Instance, but I can't find any useful property there.

Found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50475957
import groovy.transform.SourceURI


def call(){
    script {


        @SourceURI
        URI sourceUri

        withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'my-ssh', keyFileVariable: 'ssh_key', passphraseVariable: 'ssh_pass', usernameVariable: 'ssh_user')]) {
            scriptDir = new File(sourceUri.toString()).parent
            sh "sh ${scriptDir}/../resources/script1.sh -u $ssh_user -i $ssh_key -b ${env.BUILD_ID}"
        }
    }
}

--
Edit:
This only works on a singular jenkins instance. This does not work in a distributed setup.
The jenkins library is checked out on the controller, sourceUri gives you the path on the controller. Everything is executed on the agent, though, where the files do not exist.
So libraryResource copies the resources from the controller to the agent.
This leaves me with two options, both of which I find less than ideal.

recursively copy all shell files via libraryResource. This can be handled by a funtion in the library, so this at the very least doesnt leak into every jenkinsfile.

Checkout the library on every node. Maybe even add it to the path variable. Write a separate CD pipeline for this, so it self-updates.


I think I'll use the first option, as that makes it kind of seamless for users of the library.

Where do you use sourceUri?

Why do you need double sh? Like sh "sh ${scriptDir}/../resources/script1.sh ..."? Why not simply sh "${scriptDir}/../resources/script1.sh ..."?
